# Override user-edit.php to design own profile page

Tags: php, javascript, html, profiles

I have searched everywhere but can't find any relevant information on this.

I want to rearrange fields on the User profile page (wp-admin/profile.php).

Can anyone please let me know how can I make this from the theme itself. I don't want to edit the WordPress core file.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the scope of your project, I would recommend either using ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) which will allow you to create custom fields in your user based on their level, which you can then output into your theme. The outputting part though will require some coding knowledge to do.

The other option is to use a system like **Ultimate Member**, or **BuddyPress**. These will effectively turn your site into a membership based site which you can again add custom fields to, give your users a front facing user profile with a searchable members directory, if that's what you want. Both of these plugins should be very straight forward for you to get set-up with and shouldn't require any coding.